# Manual Cascaded Deletion in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am writing an SSIS package where in a SQL task, I have to delete a record from a table. This record is linked to some tables and these related tables may be related to some other tables. So when I attempt to delete a record, I should remove all the references of it in other tables first.

I know that setting Cascaded delete is the best option to achieve this. However, it’s a legacy database where this change is not allowed. Moreover, it’s a transactional database where any accidental deletes from the application should be avoided.

Is there any way that SQL Server offers to frame such cascaded delete queries? Or writing the list of deletes manually is the only option?

Comment: I always advise against using "ON  delete Cascade" for the obvious reason

Comment: could you perhaps mark the record as 'deleted' rather than a 'hard' delete?

Comment: @Mitch...not obvious enough (to me anyway). What is the reason that on delete cascade should be avoided...just the unintended consequences of accidentally deleteting rows, or is there some other reason you avoid it? I find it very useful myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that SQL Server offers to frame cascaded deletes is to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` which you have said you can't use.

It's possible to query to metadata to get a list of affected records in other tables, but it would be complicated since you want to remove the constraint (and therefore the metadata reference) before the delete.

You would need to, in a single transaction:

- Query the metadata to get a list of affected tables.  **This would need to be recursive so you can get tables affected by the first tier, then those affected by those affected by the first tier, and so on.**
- Drop the constraint.  **This will also need to be recursive for the same reasons as listed above.**
- Delete the record(s) in all affected tables
- Re-enable the constraints

Someone else may have a more elegant solution but I think this is probably it.

It could be easier to do in .NET with SQL Management Objects as well, if that's an option.

**I should clarify too that I'm not endorsing this as the potential for issues is very very high.**

I think your safest course of action is to manually write out the deletes.

Comment: If I am making a recursive deletion, what's the need for droping and re creating the constraints. Dropping the constraint is to override the rules set by the constraints right. In your suggestion, we are coming from leaf to root honoring the constraints.

Comment: However the information you have provided does help me. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @Sarav - If you leave constraints in place you will need to be sure to use the reverse order in that recursive query.  If you drop constraints the order won't matter.